# How to fix Firebird error Database already opened with engine instance, incompatible with current'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, firebird, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app with using flask_sqlalchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile(filename='settings.py', silent=True)
db = SQLAlchemy(app=app)
```

I want connect to same database from daemon. In daemon I just import db and use `db.engine.execute` for SQLAlchemy queries.
But when daemon starts main app can't connect to database.
In log I see that:

```
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE:
-902\n- I/O error during "lock" operation for file "main.fdb"\n- Database 
already opened with engine instance, incompatible with current', -902, 
335544344)
```

I trying use isolation level:

```
from fdb.fbcore import ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_LEGACY
class TPBAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app_, info, options):
        if 'isolation_level' not in options:
            options['isolation_level'] = ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_LEGACY
        return super(TPBAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app_, info, options)
```

And replace this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

To:

```
db = TPBAlchemy()
```

But this only make another error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'isolation_level' sent to create_engine(),
using configuration FBDialect_fdb/QueuePool/Engine.  Please check that the
keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

I would appreciate the full example to address my issue.

Comment: What is the connection string you use? Is that same database used by another process, what connection string does that other application use?

Comment: Also note that the problem has nothing to do with the transaction isolation level. The error means that the database is opened by two different versions of Firebird (be it server, embedded or a combination).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my connection URI is same for both firebird+fdb:////var/www/main.fdb?charset=utf8  and i use same fdb.

Comment: With that connection string you might be opening the database locally (not 100% sure), which might mean it is opened using Firebird Embedded, which could mean different versions are used. If you have Firebird server running, try it with a host name, eg `//localhost//var/....`

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string is for an embedded database. You're only allowed to have one 'connection' to an embedded database at a time.

If you have the `Loopback` provider enabled you can change your connection string to something like:

```
localhost:/var/www/main.fdb
```

or if you have the `Remote` provider enabled you will have to access your database from another remote node, and assuming your Firebird server lives on `192.168.1.100` change your connection string to

```
192.168.1.100:/var/www/main.fdb
```

If you're intending to use the `Engine12` provider (the embedded provider), then you have to stop whatever is already connected to that database because you just can't do two simultaneously users with this provider.

Also, try to set up some database aliases so you aren't specifying a database explicitly like that. In Firebird 3.0.3 check out databases.conf, where you can do something like:

```
mydatabasealias=/var/www/main.fdb
```

and your connection string would now be `mydatabasealias` instead of the whole path.