# Can't open database second time during runtime with PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

On an Ubuntu 22.4.1 server I installed Firebird 3.0.8 , Apache 2.4 and php 8.1.11 (with php8.1-interbase). When I access to the database via WEB using this script:

```
<?php
    $utente = 'MyName';
    $password = 'MyPW';
    $database = 'firebird:host=localhost;dbname=/path/to/MYDB.FDB';
    $connessione = new PDO($database, $utente, $password);
    $query = "SELECT...";
    $comando = $connessione->prepare($query);
    $comando->execute();
    $conta = 0;
    while ($riga[$conta] = $comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {$conta++;}
    for ($i = 0; $i < $conta; $i++) {
        echo "$riga[$i]["COLUMN_NAME"]";
    }
    $comando = null;
    $connessione = null;
?>
```

all goes fine. But If - during the execution of this script - I access to the database via another WEB connection or directly, using FlameRobin I receive this error message:

> I/O error during "lock" operation for file "/path/to/MYDB.FDB"
> Database already opened with engine instance, incompatible with
> current

Before using PDO I used direct access to the database with php7.2

```
$connessione = ibase_connect($database, $utente, $password);
$query = "SELECT...";
$comando = ibase_query($connessione, $query);
$conta = 0;
while ($riga[$conta] = ibase_fetch_assoc($comando)) {$conta++;}
...
```

and I got no problems. What is wrong in the script?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this answer gives some insight? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073660/2453432 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939702/firebird-embedded-multiple-user-support. I don't know Firebird, so it may have changed since those posts, but you haven't really mentioned what research or testing you've done into the issue so far.

Comment: Already seen. But I think that the answers you quote talk about embedded version of Firebird, not server one.

Comment: It may be https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/7299 . Can you try a fresh snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

This error generally means that one (or more) of the connections tries to connect using a Firebird Embedded connection. With Firebird Embedded, the database engine is loaded as a library into the address space of the client process, opening the database file directly, instead of connecting through a TCP/IP port to a Firebird server process. The default mode of Firebird (SuperServer) doesn't allow a database to be opened by multiple engines (though there can be other reasons for this error, like not being able to open some shared lock files due to wrong file access rights, etc).

According to the [PDO Firebird](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.connection.php) documentation, the connection URL for PDO Firebird doesn't have a connection property `host`. This means that you're actually only using the filename to connect, and this causes the Firebird Embedded mode to be used (if the fbclient has access to the plugins/engineXX library).

Instead, you should put the hostname in the `dbname` entry:

```
firebird:dbname=hostname:/path/to/DATABASE.FDB
```

or if you also want to specify the port:

```
firebird:dbname=hostname/port:/path/to/DATABASE.FDB
```

So in your specific case, use

```
firebird:dbname=localhost:/path/to/MYDB.FDB
```

Comment: Thank you, also for the clarity of your explanation.